# c/c++ compilation error on Mac OS Ventura

Tags: macos, gcc, g++, macos-ventura

I have a factory reset laptop with Mac OS Ventura.
I have installed home-brew and then gcc thru brew, now when I try to compile c or c++ code I get an error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the code I am trying to compile is very simple

c file:
the command that I used "gcc hi.c -o hi"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

c++ file:
the command that I used "gcc hello.cpp -o hello.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

I tried aliasing with the commands

ln -s gcc-13 gcc
ln -s g++-13 g++